# How do I fix pulseaudio stuttering?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

Using amsynth to play just a sawtooth wave.

After about 1 second, the audio will start stuttering.

On any other system, using the same settings with amsynth, the sawtooth wave will not stutter.

OS is Debian. Sound card is HDA Intel.

I've tried doing:

```
realtime-scheduling = no
```

in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

`tsched=0` does not help also, it just makes the problem worse.

Comment: Have you tried another OS on the same hardware? Same problem? Since you can reproduce it, might be best to just try bisecting the package until you can find something wrong...

Comment: When this happens again, please check if you have any `speech-dispatcher*` streams on PulseAudio. This can be due to some sites that when viewed on Firefox launch these processes and they'll just stay around.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and for me the culprit was an additional package (pulseaudio-equalizer-ladspa). I replaced it by pulseaudio-equalizer, and pulseaudio issues are gone since then.

Comment: Please mark the answer correct if it was useful. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have either package installed, so I don't think that's the issue.